# Laravel 5 - $this->middleware in controller constructor not working when called from another middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

Does anyone know why the middleware in the following example is not working?

```
class PageController extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
       $this->middleware('auth');
  }
  public function home() {
      return view('home');
  }
}
```

// this line is executed from within another middleware: `\App::make('PageController');`

I've also tried: `\App::call('PageController@home');` but it doesn't work either.

However If I call the controller from my route it works like expected:

`Route::get('test', 'PageController@home');`

But I need to call the controller from another middleware and not directly from a route.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the code design. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am trying to instantiate a class in Laravel using App::make()

Comment: Hi, the question is better explained here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-this-middleware-in-controller-constructor-not-working-when-called-from-another-middleware